# Magento 2: How to display the description and review without tabbing

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

How can i display the review and description without tabbing like the below image?[image]

Comment: Please help me to solve out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copy details.phtml file from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/

To

> app/design/frontend/company/vendor/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/

Remove  `data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'` and replace class `item` with your `custom_item`.

Refresh cache

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: What is custom_item?Sory i am new in magento 2

Comment: you can use any class

Comment: just remove  item calss

Comment: I have used the above code but I did not get the proper result. Only display the description details, not the review details.

Comment: you got review and description both from foreach

Comment: You shuold be check that before description arrive or not

Comment: No, it is not working, because review data come after tab button click.